# Can I have vim auto-format a line, rather than auto-indent it?

Tags: vim

I've recently pair programmed with a friend, and I really liked a workflow he has in emacs:

1. Write out an entire line of code out, aided by autocompletion. The line often comes out to way over 80 characters.
2. Auto-format the line according to standard C formatting rules, complete with breaking the line at appropriate places and indenting the appropriate amount.

Is there any way I can do this in vim? I know you can use the `=` operator, but the problem there is that only performs auto-indentation rather than formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gq` operator for autoformatting, but I cannot say how good the result will be: this function is used mainly for formatting text: in comments or in HTML/TeX files.

Behavior can be adjusted using `'formatexpr'` or `'formatprg'`, you can use the latter if you know good formatter program.